# How do I compile Nodejs with OpenWRT tool chain?

Tags: node.js, makefile, openwrt

I'm trying to compile Nodejs in the OpenWRT tool chain.

I want to build a Makefile to get the source code and compile it through the tool chain.

I have already followed the instructions at http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/devel/packages;

I still don't know how to build it.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this way and it works properly.
Clone this and try once.
https://github.com/nneves/openwrt_mips_ar9331_nodejs.git